# MacBook Air does not respond to cursor clicks

Tags: macbook-pro

My mac isn't responding. I can move the cursor around and click anywhere but I can't exit or quit anything because it doesn't click on the actual GUI. Closing and opening the lid doesn't help and I can't restart because I can't press that button in the menu.

What should I do?

Comment: Do you have or can you borrow a USB mouse that you can plug into it?

Comment: I've tried that sorry the problem is more in the computer

Comment: Hold onto the power button, should take about 5 seconds to shut it down hard - you will, of course, lose any existing open docs that weren't saved, unfortunately. Then try again.

Comment: press following 3 keys to force quit not responsive applications. "alt + cmd + esc" , now force quit anything in that new window. You can use the up/down arrows and the Enter (return) key so you do not need your trackpad at all.

Answer (score 1):

First I would look if any of the running apps is doing that.

Press 3 keys together

alt + cmd + esc

In the new pop up window use the up or down arrow on your keybaord and when selected hit Enter key.

You can Force quit  anything showing in there.

If that did not help to restore normal function use again the keyboard to Restart.

To reboot your Mac instantly, hit `Control-Command-Power/Eject`.

Alternatively if you hold the power button for 2 seconds a screen should show up asking you what you want to do next.

Comment: Ive just has this issue too - the Mac doesn’t respond to clicks with either the touchpad or a USB mouse. I’m not sure what to do

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem a few minutes ago. I was undoing my action in iMovie when this happened. It started to overheat soon after.

To fix this I held the power button for five seconds to shut it down hard.  It restarted and everything was alright after. I didn't lose the data on the iMovie file.

Answer (score 0):

The following just worked for me to get things working again - without any restart or loss of data.

The problem was on my Mac mini M1: it had become unreactive to

- clicks/taps on the Magic trackpad (which disconnected and reconnected fine)
- clicks with the Logitech MX Master 3 Mouse connected via the Logitech dongle
- keypresses on the keyboard (connected directly to the Mac via USB)

Here is what I did to get it to work again:

**I opened my MacBook** (which I had previously set up as a linked display so that I could use it to control my Mac mini and vice versa), **pushed the mouse pointer over to my Mac mini and clicked on stuff.** No app in particular. After that, the devices connected directly to the Mac mini started to work again.

I'm not sure if have to set the linked display up before the problem appears, but if you haven't set it up, it's worth trying whether you can do it on one device while the other is non-reactive.